# Understanding @Enable... annotations concurrency

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cache, spring-boot-starter, jsr107

We have a project that uses spring-boot-cache-starter, registering an `ehCache` `CacheManager` implementation, and spreading `@Cacheables` accross the code.

Then, some other team created an starter, that basically relies on the default configuration autconfigured by `spring-boot-cache` starter (hashmap) for its own processing of `@Cacheable` methods.

Both codes contain the `@EnableCaching` annotation, and our issue is that the behavior is different in case we comment our main project's @EnableCaching annotation.

1. If we don't comment `@EnableCaching` in our project, when we use the custom starter, everything works fine. `@Cacheables` from the
   starter are indexed and resolved in the starter scope but
   `@Cacheables` from our domain are resolved in our `ehcache`.
2. If we comment `@EnableCaching` in our project, then both the starter and our project's `@Cacheables` are tried to be resolved
   against our `ehCache` implementation.

This breaks a lot of preconceptions I had so far:

1. I always thought an annotation such as `@Enable`... applied to all the context, regardless of the placement (starter/application configuration), and regardless of whether it was found once or twice when scanning all `@Configuration` classes.
2. Why does the case work when both annotations are there, I guess the `CacheManager` in the spring-boot-cache-starter is a `@ConditionalOnBean`, so in that case I would expect both projects using the `ehcache` bean for resolving, not each one's domain

*P.S*: the `@EnableCaching` found in our main project is placed on an inner static @Configuration class. Could this be significant?

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to answer your question if you don't reveal what the custom starter does. In particular, this looks weird to me:

> @Cacheables from the starter are indexed and resolved in the starter scope but @Cacheables from our domain are resolved in our ehcache.

Your preconceptions 1 is valid: it doesn't matter where you you put the annotation or if you add it more than once. It will just enable caching for the whole `ApplicationContext`. In the case of Spring Boot, that will trigger the auto-configuration unless a custom `CacheManager` bean is defined in user's configuration.

The "each one's domain" sounds broken to me. Are you sure this is what's happening? If you want to store in several cache managers there is not a lot of different ways:

1. You need to define a `CacheResolver` and refer to it in the `@Cacheable` annotations (or `@CacheConfig`)
2. You need a special `CacheManager` that knows where to find the caches in each underlying stores

If each domain has a standard use of `@Cacheable` it will go against *the* `CacheManager`. If you notice the behaviour you are describing, it has nothing to do with `@EnableCaching` at all.